# Implicit conversion operator doesn't kick in with operator overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, conversion-operator

Consider the following example:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

struct Location {
    unsigned line;

    template<typename CharT, typename Traits>
    operator std::basic_string<CharT, Traits>() const {
        std::basic_ostringstream<CharT, Traits> ss;
        ss << line;
        return ss.str();
    }
};

int main() 
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    Location loc{42};

    std::string s1 = "Line: "s.append(loc) + "\n"s; // fine
    //std::string s2 = "Line: "s + loc + "\n"s; // error
}
```

The commented line causes a compilation error: `no match for 'operator+'`. Why? My initial thought was that it would first use `operator std::string` to convert and then perform the call to `operator+`, the same way it does for `.append`.

It is only one level of implicit conversion, so it should be performed and it should be taken into account, no?

<kbd>[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/2b1o5h)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry for asking, but I don't see to get the working code. What is `s`?

Comment: @gsamaras http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Comment: Right @Holt, thanks!

Comment: The problem here is that when you do `.append`, the template arguments are already instantiated during construction of `"Line"s`, so there is no template argument deduction taking place (`.append` wants `std::string`), but the `+` operator is templated, so you need to deduce `CharT`, `Traits` and `Allocator`, and you cannot because the compiler cannot match `basic_string<...>` against `Location` - You don't even reach the conversion phase, it's the overload phase that fails.

Comment: @Holt Thank you. A technical explanation is what I was searching for. I'd accept if you posted as a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operator is templated, thus the template arguments need to be deduced. You cannot do that, since the compiler tries to match `basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>` to your `Location`, and it fails.

So the problem is the overloading, not the conversion, since the code actually never reaches that point.

Change this:

```
std::string s2 = "Line: "s + loc + "\n"s;
```

to this:

```
std::string s2 = "Line: "s + std::string(loc) + "\n"s;
```

and you should be fine, since if you look closely at the compiler error, it mentions:

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:22:32: note:   'Location' is not derived from 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'
   std::string s2 = "Line: "s + loc + "\n"s; // error
                                ^~~
```

and other similar messages.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit cast to std::string works for me: https://godbolt.org/g/WZG78z

```
    std::string s2 = "Line: "s + std::string(loc) + "\n"; // was error
```